# Is autoimmune disease associated with self-reactive B cells?

Tags: immunology, pathology, literature, autoimmune

I'm a bit of an amateur, so excuse what may be a very naive question, but I somewhat understand how B cells that are self-reactive (bind to endogenous epitopes) are selected out during development. I also know that autoimmune disease is caused by the immune system persistently attacking specific components of the body, which sounds a lot like self-reactive B cells.

Is autoimmune disease associated with (dare I say caused by?) errors in this self-reactive B cell selection process? Any useful references so I can hopefully become less amateurish?